# Remove indentation at the beginning of subsections (using amsbook)

Tags: indentation, amsbook

Is there a way to get rid of the indentation at the beginning of subsections when using the documentclass `amsbook`?

See the attached image for an example (where the problematic indentation is marked blue):

[image: example]

The example was generated using the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{This is a chapter}
\section{This is a section}
\subsection{This is a subsection}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this code. Put the redefinition of `\subsection` from `\makeatletter` to `\makeatother` in your preamble.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}%
    \z@{.5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{-.5em}%
    {\normalfont\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{This is a chapter}
\section{This is a section}
\subsection{This is a subsection}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]